# What determines a battery's voltage?

Tags: voltage, batteries

My understanding is that a 1.5 V battery with 100 mAh capacity and a 3.0 V battery with 50 mAh capacity could have the same coulombs of charged particles.

So what is different about the battery that determines the actual voltage?

I thought of things like internal resistance, or how close they are to each other through the dielectric material like in a capacitor.

Comment: 1 Amp is one coulomb per second, so 100 mah is 0.1A *3600 s = 360 coulombs of charge.  50 mah is therefore 180 coulombs, or half as much.

Comment: Chemistry determines a cell's voltage. That and the number of cells determines the battery voltage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My understanding is that the a 1.5 volt battery with 100mah capacity and 3.0 volt battery with 50mah capacity could have the same coulombs of charged particles.

Not really. 0.1Ah is 360 coulombs of charge, 0.05Ah is 180 coulombs of charge. The battery capacity is in the units of charge - 1 mAh is just another way to write 3.6 Coulombs.

> So what is different about the battery that determines the actual voltage?

The differences are electrochemical potential between electrodes in a cell, and the number of cells in series.

> I thought of things like internal resistance or how close they are to each other through the dielectric material like in a capacitor.

Internal resistance affects the efficiency of the battery, but doesn't change the internal capacity. When the battery is discharged at an infinitisemally small current, the internal resistance of the battery doesn't play a large role, and the externally measurable capacity approaches the electrochemical capacity of the cell.

Batteries generally don't use dielectrics, in the sense that their properties don't depend on distributing charge throughout a dielectric. Instead, batteries distribute ions on the electrodes, and the electrolyte itself conducts as soon as charge flows between electrodes - otherwise, the battery would be an open circuit.

Comment: "Not really. 0.1Ah is 360 coulombs of charge, 0.05Ah is 180 coulombs of charge. The battery capacity is in the units of charge - 1 mAh is just another way to write 3.6 Coulombs." If I have 2  x1.5v batteries each containing 1 mah, in series they are they will be double the voltage but still 1 mah, in parallel the voltage is still 1.5v but 2mah even though both configurations have the same 2*3.6 coulombs .

Comment: "The differences are electrochemical potential between electrodes in a cell, and the number of cells in series." that's what I am trying to understand, are voltages fixed by the chemistry they use or can you have two batteries with the same chemistry but different voltages?

Comment: The chemistry determines the cell voltage. Might be worth noting that the term ‘battery’ is a collection of cells although it gets used loosely for a cell or multiple cells.

Comment: @AndrewT The chemistry is used to mean what stuff the cell is built with. But that doesn't describe the cell **state**. The voltage you get from a cell depends on its state when you performed the measurement. A cell can be fully charged, overcharged, fully discharged, over-discharged, charged to a reverse potential, etc. You're probably asking about **nominal voltage** - you have to be specific. It is the nominal voltage that depends on the cell chemistry, with the assumption that the cell is fully charged. As soon as you "touch it", the voltage changes.

Comment: Answered thank you, for anyone else reading this and trying to understand this webpage also help me understand the concept. https://www.quora.com/Why-cant-the-United-States-make-1-5-volt-lithium-ion-rechargeable-batteries-European-rechargeable-batteries-run-3-7-volts